# How to create k-means clustering in geopandas dataframe?

Tags: datagrid, polygon, k-means, geopandas

I want to build k-means clustering on my map

[image: This is a map that I want to build kmeans clustering]
But I end up with this result:
[image: My result]

So how to build kmeans clustering depends on color indicator values? Which means clustering points are closer to the darker areas. Or should I use different approaches?